# getBoundingClientRect() values are bigger (2x) on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, device, offset

Javascript's `getBoundingClientRect()` values are 2 times bigger on my mobile devices.
If you run the code below in a desktop browser it is correct.
Then run the code eg. in responsive developer tools with a fixed device height.
In chrome: 640px height, i scroll down to the bottom, i reload it and see -1936px.
How can i get the correct value 640 +- 10px on mobile devices?
Is there a ratio, for high resolution displays or any other factor?

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="output" style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:green; font-size:30pt;"><script>document.write(document.getElementById('output').getBoundingClientRect().top);</script></div>
    <div style="height:100%; width:100%; font-size:30pt;">
    <script>document.write(document.getElementById('output').getBoundingClientRect().top);</script></div>
</body>
</html>
```

On my HTCM9 the value is exactly 2 times bigger...
Even Jquery functions and other solutions seems not work.

[image]

Comment: I cannot replicate your result. Can you post a snippet (using the Stack snippet tool)?

Comment: Does not work with a snippet but i made an image...